# How do i draw a semitransparent white line?

Tags: android, line, android-canvas, paint, draw

I have the hexcode as #70ffffff for the color and all i do is canvas.drawline() and paint has the color set to that hex.

```
p = new Paint();
p.setColor(R.color.transparentwhite);
p.setStrokeWidth(15);
canvas.drawLine(a.getCenterX(), a.getCenterY(), 
                          a.getPrevious().getCenterX(), a.getPrevious().getCenterY(), p);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try this..

```
p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#70ffffff"));
```

instead of

```
p.setColor(R.color.transparentwhite);
```

Comment: works perfectly. thank you! do you know why it was changing it to black?

Comment: @Robin Please upvote it so more helpful to other. and "#000000" uesd then it will be black.